# Approver Comments Empty

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an Approval Workflow set up. When a member of staff requests Annual Leave they are given the option to view the comments from the approver. So when it is rejected they can see why.

When I go to reject the Annual Leave the comments don't show up. Please see images below.

[image]
[image]

I have also noticed that on the emails the comment is blank.

Comment: I removed the workflow and custom list and started from scratch and it works now.

Comment: I can't mark any of these as the correct answers as they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

I see that in the Approve/Reject dialog, the field is labeled **Comment**, while in the list view it's labeled **Comment*s***. Which means you have two different fields with similar names. I'm pretty sure that's the source of your problem.

Comment: The comments field is for the staff to write in. E.g. "Want annual leave for holiday". Then the approve comment would say something such as "Rejected due to too many staff off". The comments from staff show up, just not from the approver.

Answer (score 0):

We had to submit a case with Microsoft about this as we experienced the same thing. If you are running a 2013 workflow, the approval comments do not make it back, this is a design decision apparently. If you use a 2010 workflow, it will show the comments as you'd expect, but you lose out on all the nice new features of 2013 workflows.

Comment: I'm using the 2010 workflow but it still doesn't work however! If I then click approve/reject a second time and add the comments it actually shows up. It's very weird!

Comment: Ahh, Microsoft. We can always count on you to make design decisions that make absolutely no sense. "Yes, Tech Support? There's a hole in the bottom of my coffee cup." "Ok, can you reboot? Uninstall and reinstall? Try a different coffee cup? Oh, I found it now. This behavior is by design. If I have helped you, please rate this answer as helpful."